# StructureMap and facades

Tags: .net, ioc-container, structuremap

I'm thinking of defining a facade for part of an application which is returned by an IoC container, in my case StructureMap. The facade has a constructor with no arguments that sets a default implementations, and another one so I can define custom implementations of the different subsystem objects the facade manage.

However, since StructureMap is trying to make an instance of the facade calling the constructor with the most arguments, it fails if no implementation of the other subsystems is registered.

My question is: Is there any way of telling StructureMap to try use the following constructor in line if it cannot use the main one? Or must I tell StructureMap which constructor to select?

Comment: Maybe a bit of sample code will help with some visualization.

Comment: If possible, always have a single constructor with arguments. Don't make a default constructor that initializes the type. This way your type is still tightly coupled with concrete dependencies, which makes it hard to swap. Let StructureMap do its job.

Comment: Having a single constructor with arguments, although still being handful, would mostly beat the purpose of having the facade in this case. About adding a bit of sample, I don't know if that is really needed, after all, my question doesn't require much of code. Having a class with multiple constructors, StructureMap will choose the first one with the greater number if arguments, what I want to know is if StructureMap can somehow use the other constructors as fallbacks in case of exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge it's not possible to have StructureMap trying to resolve an instance and to fall back to alternate ctors if not successful with the greediest.

I think that it would be a good idea to wire up the facade's dependendencies using StructureMap as well and specify defaults there. Perhaps it's possible to use a Null object implementation as default for the subsystems that might be missing.

Comment: I've thought of it as well, but I'd want to know if StructureMap is able to do what I ask. I think it would be a nice addition, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a delegate that will create your type as follows:

```
container.Configure(r => r.For<IFacade>().Use(() => new RealFacade()));
```

Comment: Good point, is better than my solution (why is that a familiar feeling)

Comment: Yeah, I'm also aware of it, although I prefer to use a constructor selector in this case. Just my personal taste anyway, as I don't know if there are any advantages or disadvantages with them, and maybe this other option is better, maybe this well could be the subject of other thread.

Comment: @Neverbirth: Calling a constructor directly can have disadvantages, depending on the DI container you use. *Simple Injector* for instance, will not do any post initialization on that type (using the `RegisterInitializer` method). *StructureMap* on the other hand, does (using the `OnCreationForAll` method). As far as I know, *Unity* doesn't even have such a feature. Either way, when you add a dependency to your constructor, you have to change the DI configuration. That's the obvious downside.